# Is it possible to split NewRelic Web monitoring into two applications, Mobile and Non-Mobile

Tags: php, asp.net, newrelic

Using NewRelic in both .Net and PHP world.  Is it possible to manually instrument the application such that our /m/  (mobile) site is instrumented as one application and our / (non-mobile) site is instrumented separately?

I have read a few threads that show how to ignore transactions and/or manually instrument only the parts of the site you want to track.  Ideally I would like to manually instrument the whole site and use two different NewRelic application ID so we can see the Mobile performance in one application (Mobile = HTML 5 app, not native) and the desktop performance in another.

Right now iPhone Safari is brining my performance from 2 seconds up to 7 seconds..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PHP you can set the app name with the new relic PHP API

newrelic_set_appname (name)

Shouldn't that work?

See https://newrelic.com/docs/php/the-php-api for the details

You could also set the PHP ini value in your webserver settings (eg. apache) depending if your URL starts with /m/ or not. (the ini settings are described here https://newrelic.com/docs/php/php-agent-phpini-settings )

Comment: Looks like it should, I was looking in the custom intrumentation documentation and missed this, thnks

Answer (score 0):

In .Net the most granular you can get with Application name assignment is at the App.config level. If the mobile and root site pull from the same config hierarchy, I don't think there is anything you can do.

You could monitor key transactions and focus less on the overall application response time and just those transactions specific to each section of the application.

https://newrelic.com/docs/transactions-dashboards/key-transactions